# Vim with vim.fireplace closes/hangs when trying to open a Clojure file

Tags: vim, clojure

I installed vim and vim.fireplace, did `lein repl` and tried to open core.clj generated by `lein new`. I'm using Windows. A cmd window opened and tried to do `lein classpath`. After a few seconds gvim just closed. I tried with plain vim: I could open the file, but when I tried to evaluate someting (`cqp` and then typed `1` and pressed Enter) vim hangs. Vim `has('python')` == 1. What could be wrong?

Vim version 7.3 and fireplace version https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace/commit/4f6b8e52376dc9973ca0478b750578b681681b55

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your are trying to evaluate a form without any repl connected.
Then vim-fireplace will fall back to use `java clojure.main` which assumes classpath.vim installed.

Could you check whether your vim is already connected to the repl?

BTW, why didn't you ask on issue list of vim-fireplace?